# cannot convert from 'TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Enums.DmlTriggerType' to 'TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Abstracts.ITableDependencyFilter'

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.2, sqldependency

I'm trying to follow [this](http://elvanydev.com/SignalR-Core-SqlDependency-part2/) tutorial, but getting this error

> Argument 6: cannot convert from
>   'TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Enums.DmlTriggerType' to
>   'TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Abstracts.ITableDependencyFilter'
>   (CS1503)

Also, in the same tutorial author used Hubcontext in startup file like this

```
services.AddScoped<IHubContext<NonProductionHub>, HubContext<NonProductionHub>>();
```

I'm not sure to whether its correct or not because I'm getting the following error on `HubContext` and not on `IHubContext`

> The type or namespace name 'HubContext<>' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public class InventoryDatabaseSubscription : IDatabaseSubscription
        {
            private bool disposedValue = false;
            private readonly IInventoryRepository _repository;
            private readonly IHubContext<NonProductionHub> _hubContext;
            private SqlTableDependency<Apps> _tableDependency;

            public InventoryDatabaseSubscription(IInventoryRepository repository, IHubContext<NonProductionHub> hubContext)
            {
                _repository = repository;
                _hubContext = hubContext;            
            }

            public void Configure(string DefaultConnection)
            {
                _tableDependency = new SqlTableDependency<Apps>(DefaultConnection, null, null, null, null, DmlTriggerType.All);
                _tableDependency.OnChanged += Changed;
                _tableDependency.OnError += TableDependency_OnError;
                _tableDependency.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for receiving notifications...");
            }

            private void TableDependency_OnError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"SqlTableDependency error: {e.Error.Message}");
            }

            private void Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Apps> e)
            {
                if (e.ChangeType != ChangeType.None)
                {
                    // TODO: manage the changed entity
                    var changedEntity = e.Entity;
                    _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("UpdateCatalog", _repository.Apps);
                }
            }

            #region IDisposable

            ~InventoryDatabaseSubscription()
            {
                Dispose(false);
            }

            protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (!disposedValue)
                {
                    if (disposing)
                    {
                        _tableDependency.Stop();
                    }

                    disposedValue = true;
                }
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                Dispose(true);
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }

            #endregion
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Argument 6: cannot convert from 'TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Enums.DmlTriggerType' to 'TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Abstracts.ITableDependencyFilter' (CS1503)

From the error , you could go to the definition of SqlTableDependency method to check the arguments contained

```
public SqlTableDependency(string connectionString, string tableName = null, string schemaName = null, 
                          IModelToTableMapper<T> mapper = null, IUpdateOfModel<T> updateOf = null, 
                          ITableDependencyFilter filter = null, DmlTriggerType notifyOn = DmlTriggerType.All, 
                          bool executeUserPermissionCheck = true, bool includeOldValues = false);
```

The value `DmlTriggerType.All` should be the seventh instead of sixth, and the value of the sixth parameter is null , change the code like below :

```
_tableDependency = new SqlTableDependency<Apps>(DefaultConnection, null, null, null, null, null, DmlTriggerType.All);
```

> The type or namespace name 'HubContext<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The `HubContext` allows you to send messages to your connected clients. It has many of the same features to communicate with clients as when you are inside of a Hub.

In order to get an instance of the `HubContext`, you need to be using dependency injection by specifying you want an `IHubContext<T>` in the constructor. Where `T` is your Hub. Refer to the following example :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
   private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;

   public HomeController(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
   {
      _hubContext = hubContext;
   }
}
```

Referece :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2